# how to find a delimiter missing from text file?

Tags: java

The program should read the match data from a text file. Each line in the file contains the data for a specific match. The format of each line within the file is as follows:

```
home_team_name : away_team_name : home_team_score : away_team_score
```

Notice how a colon character (:) is used to separate different parts of the input (the field delimiter).

The following is an example of the typical lines of data within the file.

```
Arsenal : Spurs : 2 : 1
Everton : Liverpool : 1 : 1
Huddersfield : Chelsea: 2 : 1
```

The data stored in the file could be corrupted. For this requirement, the program must examine each line of data read from the file, identify invalid data and report these to the user via messages on the console.  At a minimum, the program should check and validate the following possible issues–
-   The field delimiter may be missing or wrong field delimiter is used.

Comment: What have you tried? E.g. are you using `split(":")` to parse the lines? If so, then a simple `if (arr.length != 4) { /*report bad line*/ }` would do.

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you'll have to use two methods of the `String` class as well as a `BufferedReader`. Here's a little bit of code

```
import java.io;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = "c:\temp\in.txt";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                String[] fields = line.split(":");
                String[] trimmedFields = new String[fields.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < trimmedField.length; i++) {
                    trimmedFields[i] = fields[i].trim();
                }

                //do your verification with the trimmedFields
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split each line at ':' and check the array length to check if team names and scores are available:

```
     boolean isDataComplete = line.split(":").length ==4;
```

Check if 3rd and 4th elements are integer values

```
    boolean isValidScore = line.split(":")[2].trim().matches("\\d+") &&  line.split(":")[3].trim().matches("\\d+")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, make a `for` loop. This one would check the character you are inside the actual lane.

However, to do this, you should make a limitation on each line, to make the program know when you ended a line. For example `|Arsenal : Spurs : 2 : 1|`.

Given this, you would do something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));  
try {  
    String line;
    int lineDelimeters=0;
    int numberOfDelimeters=0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       for(char c:line.toCharArray){
          if(c=='|')
             lineDelimeters++;
          else if(c==':')
             numberOfDelimeters++;
          if(numberOfDelimeters<4 && lineDelimeters==2)
             System.out.println("The file is corrupted.")
       }
    }
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```